# Weird random width on matplotlib candlestick_ohlc function

Tags: python, matplotlib, finance

Im using `candlestick_ohlc` from matplotlib to draw short candlestick patterns, I have the settings for `width` as `0.01`. and always drawing 6 candles.

Most of the times the bars look as expected, but 1 out of 5 of each images (more or less) are drawn with a way bigger width that breaks the graph.

[image: graph exemple]

Here's an example of how I use my function:

```
candlestick_ohlc(ax1, candles, width=0.01,colorup='green', colordown='red')
```

and an example of the data being processed:

```
[[7.37151000e+05 1.30622000e+00 1.30658000e+00 1.30597000e+00  1.30610000e+00]
 [7.37151010e+05 1.30609000e+00 1.30619000e+00 1.30500000e+00  1.30595000e+00]
 [7.37151021e+05 1.30594000e+00 1.30621000e+00 1.30575000e+00  1.30602000e+00]
 [7.37151031e+05 1.30603000e+00 1.30644000e+00 1.30603000e+00  1.30632000e+00]
 [7.37151042e+05 1.30633000e+00 1.30648000e+00 1.30622000e+00  1.30648000e+00]
 [7.37151052e+05 1.30644000e+00 1.30661000e+00 1.30551000e+00  1.30553000e+00]]

[[7.37151010e+05 1.30609000e+00 1.30619000e+00 1.30500000e+00  1.30595000e+00]
 [7.37151021e+05 1.30594000e+00 1.30621000e+00 1.30575000e+00  1.30602000e+00]
 [7.37151031e+05 1.30603000e+00 1.30644000e+00 1.30603000e+00  1.30632000e+00]
 [7.37151042e+05 1.30633000e+00 1.30648000e+00 1.30622000e+00  1.30648000e+00]
 [7.37151052e+05 1.30644000e+00 1.30661000e+00 1.30551000e+00  1.30553000e+00]
 [7.37151062e+05 1.30553000e+00 1.30590000e+00 1.30529000e+00  1.30573000e+00]]

[[7.37151060e+05 1.30561000e+00 1.30561000e+00 1.30549000e+00  1.30551000e+00]
 [7.37151060e+05 1.30550000e+00 1.30568000e+00 1.30550000e+00  1.30568000e+00]
 [7.37151061e+05 1.30565000e+00 1.30580000e+00 1.30562000e+00  1.30580000e+00]
 [7.37151062e+05 1.30580000e+00 1.30583000e+00 1.30578000e+00  1.30578000e+00]
 [7.37151062e+05 1.30579000e+00 1.30590000e+00 1.30566000e+00  1.30573000e+00]
 [7.37151063e+05 1.30573000e+00 1.30574000e+00 1.30550000e+00  1.30561000e+00]]
```

Comment: What versions of python and matplotlib?

Comment: In those cases where it doesn't work out, you need to further reduce the width. More precisely, the width should never be larger than the difference between two successive x data points.

Comment: @WilliamMiller Python 3.6.8 Matplotlib 3.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ImportanceOfBeingErnest said "In those cases where it doesn't work out, you need to further reduce the width. More precisely, the width should never be larger than the difference between two successive x data points."

That said, **there is a new version of matplotlib finance that handles this automatically for you**.  You can find the new version, along with documentation, here:

https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/

Install with:   `pip install --upgrade mplfinance`

NOTE: The package name no longer has the dash or underscore:
It is now mplfinance (not mpl-finance, nor mpl_finance)